# Ethernet connection is not showing in my ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

These are outputs of some useful commands:- 
May it helps...

1.-> ifconfig
output-->

```
      lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:9262 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9262 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:845156 (845.1 KB)  TX bytes:845156 (845.1 KB)

      wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:ca:94:3e:ec:ef  
      inet addr:192.168.43.229  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e2ca:94ff:fe3e:ecef/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:223666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:217706
      TX packets:180946 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:243037937 (243.0 MB)  TX bytes:16583971 (16.5 MB)
      Interrupt:16 
      (2).  cat /etc/nework/interfaces :->
      output--> # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
      auto lo
      iface lo inet loopback

      (3). ifup eth0 :->
      output-->  Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0.

      (4) lspci -nn :->
      output--> 
       00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation CoreProcessor    
       Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09) 
       00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd   Generation      

     C ore Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)

     00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
     00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
     00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
     00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b4)
     00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 04)
     00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 04)
     00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 04)
     00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 04)
    01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

that it..

Comment: Output indicates that the only network controller you have is the Broadcom wireless. aka wlan0

Comment: May not be eth0 may be p2p1 or enp2s0 or similar. Run [ifconfig -a] to list all of your interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

By default `eth0` doesn't start sometimes. Therefore try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Then `ifconfig -a`

Also check your `/etc/network/interfaces` file and verify the `eth0` interface if exists.

Hope this helps. Let me know.

Comment: checking /etc/network/interfaces--->   
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Comment: did this help? or not ? what do you see ?